# save richtextbox to file C#

Tags: c#, save, richtextbox

I am having trouble saving from richtextbox to .txt file

here is the code:

```
if (richTextBox1.Text != String.Empty)
            {
                string dir = @"c:\\logs\\" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd_MMM_yy");
                string path = @"c:\\logs\\" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd_MMM_yy") + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss") + ".txt";
                if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                }

                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    File.Create(path);
                    richTextBox1.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                }

            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
```

where I am going wrong ?! It says it cannot access the file because it is being used by another process... Any help would be welcome

Thanks,
dnisko

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can avoid create file line because `SaveFile` will create file for you.

`File.Create` will return open stream for the file, you need to close it before access again. Do as below If you need to use create file anyway

```
using(File.Create(path));
richTextBox1.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

Comment: The SaveFile method is enough to deal with any situation. File.Create(path); can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`File.Create` returns the Stream of the file created.

As long as you do not dispose it, it will keep the file open

You can also use the Stream to directly write to the file. Using the `using` statement helps getting around any allocation issues.

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
            // Add some information to the file.
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }
```

Comment: The SaveFile method is enough to deal with any situation. File.Create(path); can be deleted.

Comment: Thx to MichaC you answered to the question, why there is a problem because the file stayed open after creation, people could forgot to dispose. It's also true in this case SaveFile method will be enough, but it's always good to remember basic things to people.

Answer (score 0):

```
 richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

Answer (score 0):

to save the file

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender , EventArgs e)
{   
     string  _Path=@"C:\temp\Untitled.txt";
      if (!File.Exists(_Path))
        {
            StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(_Path);
            SW.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
            SW.Close();
        }
        else if (File.Exists(_Path))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This File is Exists");
            SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog();
            SFD.FileName = "";
            SFD.AddExtension = true;
            SFD.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            DialogResult result= SFD.ShowDialog();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty( SFD.FileName))
            {
                return;
            }
            else if(result==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(SFD.FileName);
                SW.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text);
                SW.Close();
            }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `SaveFile()` method is gone. So another way to save is with

```
TextRange range = new(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
FileStream fStream = new(fileName, FileMode.Create);
range.Save(fStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
fStream.Close();
```